# Azure Speech to Text: Custom speech model - related text "pro ceed"

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

We are running a custom speech model use Azure's Cognitive Services / Speech-to-text and I'm running across an issue where users reported "proceed" is transcribed as "pro ceed".  As it turns out, our related text has "pro ceed" in it - which explains the cause.

However, the related text was originally uploaded with the term "proceed" (not "pro ceed").  Here is a sample with just the single word:

[image]

The text file is UTF-8 with BOM

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Can you supply a link to the original file in which it is spelled correctly?

Comment: @DavidCrook here is the file: https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ara7S9eOjfD5rT1zFbKE0Y9sJnVM?e=4Zg4H3

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed and will be rolled out in the next days.